# Display posts with date wordpress default

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to display last posts with WordPress date, not date from server.

```
<?php 
$week = date( 'W' );
$year = date( 'Y' );
$query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $year . '&w=' . $week );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();

    // Page title
    the_title(); 


} // end while

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

// Save memory
unset( $query );

;?>
```

what is wrong?
How i can use to show last x day posts with date wordpress default?

Comment: what ddo you mean by last x day posts.   do you mean yesterdays post

Comment: I mean e.g. last 7day with date from wordpress not from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to study about date query. 
Anyways following should work

```
<?php 
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,  
  'date_query' => array(
     array(
           'after' => '7 days ago'
           )
     )
  );

$query = new WP_Query($args);

while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();

    // Page title
    the_title(); 


} // end while

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

// Save memory
unset( $query );

;
?>
```

Comment: thank you, but i want show by date not by time.
e.g. all posts last 7 day by sort by date not by time hour.

Comment: please see the edited code

Comment: If i set this:
'after' => '1 days ago'
i have 5 posts 1 in 2015-09-01 and 4 in 2015-08-31, this only show 4 posts, from 1 in 2015-09-01 and 3 in 2015-08-31.
I want to show all posts on the date specified, regardless of the time.

Comment: you 'll have to use 'posts_per_page' => -1 as arguments for WP_Query to display all the posts and ignore the pagination.   Please see the edited code